# CSS animation applied to multiple elements results in animation speed differences

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I created an animation that is supposed to move the element from the top to the bottom of the page. I created 4 objects and applied the animation to them. To my surprise they are moving with different speed. I'm a bit confused. What is going on?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(12, 12, 13)
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.object {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
}

.slider {
  animation: 10s linear infinite slide;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-top: 0%
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="object slider"></div>
    <div class="object slider" style="margin-left:30%"></div>
    <div class="object slider" style="margin-left:60%"></div>
    <div class="object slider" style="margin-left:90%"></div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/on6t18hy/1/

Comment: It's something to do with the inline margin I think and the `block`nature of the divs - https://jsfiddle.net/df4xjnc7/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are block elements so they are simply above each other and each one on a new line. We don't see this clearly because they are very small but if you increase their size it will be trivial:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(12, 12, 13)
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.object {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.slider {
  /*animation: 10s linear infinite slide;*/
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-top: 0%
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="object slider"></div>
    <div class="object slider" style="margin-left:30%"></div>
    <div class="object slider" style="margin-left:60%"></div>
    <div class="object slider" style="margin-left:90%"></div>
  </div>
```

You can clearly see that each one is on a line and increasing the margin-top of the first line will push the other lines and so on.

Add the animation to only the first one and you will see what is happening. Then add to the others and you will understand:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(12, 12, 13)
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.object {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.slider {
  animation: 10s linear infinite slide;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    margin-top: 0%
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="object slider"></div>
    <div class="object " style="margin-left:30%"></div>
    <div class="object " style="margin-left:60%"></div>
    <div class="object " style="margin-left:90%"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the "container" and each "object". You can see, that the margins are multiplying each other. So the first one has the "normal" margin, the second one has 2x"normal" and so on.
When you position the "object" absolute it won't happen any more.